# Vaadin 7 -> com.vaadin.ui.CheckBox -> ".getValue()" does always return "false"

Tags: checkbox, vaadin, vaadin7

I use a Vaadin7 `com.vaadin.ui.CheckBox` with Java 1.8 on a Wildfly Application Server.

I have a PopUpDialog with the following checkbox configuration:

```
checkBox1.addValueChangeListener(event -> // Java 8
                LOGGER.info("property Value: "+ event.getProperty().getValue().toString()+
                        " getValue Value: "+checkBox1.getValue()));
```

When I click the `checkBox1` in the User Interface in the WebBrowser the `ValueChangeListener` gets called.

The first `property Value "event.getProperty().getValue().toString()"` returns the correct `true/false` state of the checkbox.

But the `checkBox1.getValue()` which I want to use in my PopUpDialog class methods to access the `true/false == clicked/not clicked` state of the checkobox returns always `false` even if I call it in the `ValueChangeListener`

Can someone help me why the "getValue()" method does not return the correct state ?

-----------------EDIT---------------

One solution is to use the ValueChangeListener to set the value of the Checkbox:

```
checkBox1.addValueChangeListener(event ->
                checkBox1.setValue(
(Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue()
                                   ));
```

But normally the value should be set without a listener setting it manually, correct ?

Comment: can you try clicking the checkbox multiple times and tell me whether `checkBox1.getValue()` will always be false, or if it's always the wrong value (true when it should be false)? What I'm getting at here is maybe the checkbox is in some kind of lazy valuechangemode or something. Although I don't think that is a thing for checkboxes. textfields have it for example

Comment: And about your edit - yes that is really messed up and should definitely not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

what is a `PopUpDialog` class? Is it some add-on? (Haven't found myself by briefly googling)

I've tried your scenario with a `PopupView` and value is always returned correctly. Vaadin version is 7.7.13

```java
CheckBox cb=new CheckBox();
cb.addValueChangeListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Event value" + e.getProperty().getValue());
            System.out.println("cb value: " + cb.getValue());
});
VerticalLayout popupContent = new VerticalLayout();
Button getValue=new Button("Value", e->{
            Notification.show("CB value:" + cb.getValue());
});
popupContent.addComponents(cb,getValue);
PopupView popup = new PopupView("Pop it up", popupContent);
layout.addComponent(popup);
setContent(layout);
```

Is there anything I've missed in my example?

Edit: And Checkbox, of course, should return a correct value. Otherwise, it's a bug